# Visual Studio Code editor is not taking the entire space

Tags: visual-studio-code

Any idea on how to make the editor use the entire space?
Couldn't find much of a solution for long

[image: My Editor]

Comment: do you want to remove sidebar?

Comment: No. The area between the line number and the scroll bar of the editor - It usually extends from the sidebar to the extreme right of the window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click on view and then click on Toggle Centered Layout.
I hope it will help you to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest VScode versions, Toggle Centered Layout is not visible on View. You can call from command palete > View: Toggle Centered Layout.